# Securely Storing Password Hashes in Cache

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, authentication, caching, hash

I am making a back-end server as a personal project. Currently, when someone registers, their password is hashed with Bcrypt, and saved in the database. However, querying the database every-time I need to verify that the request came from the authenticated user seems to be too much. As a result, I began to wonder about caching these in the server's memory. I assume that it is unsafe to store an un-hashed password in this memory. What is the most secure way to implement this? I could cache the Bcrypte'd copy of the passwords, and then just verify that the user's password matches the cached Bcrypt copy, but if I can I would like to use bcrypt as little as possible too. I assume that storing a password and its Bcrypt'd version in the cache together, even if not linked to a username, is a bad idea. Is there anything else I can do while keeping security + performance in mind?

Comment: Why is querying the database each time "too much"? It's great to consider the alternatives but it sounds like you are over-engineering it.

Comment: I don't have the best hardware resources, and if possible, I want to minimize the amount of database queries and resource-intensive jobs that are performed. However, if this at all compromises security I will endure it.

Comment: I think storing the hashed password in cache is fine. Storing the clear text password is not. Unless you have data telling you otherwise, my default recommendation is always to do the simplest thing first (in other words, forget caching and just query the database).

Comment: By the way, how often do you think you need to check the password? Only when the user logs in, right? Not on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Caching clear-text passwords & its hashes is generally not a good idea. Security comes with a cost, here your performance.

If you don't need top-notch security (i.e. slower hashing), you can go for fast hashing solutions based on SHA512.

For database performance, try to tune the database caches for faster retrieval.